# Installing ROS on Mavericks - "rviz: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [urdfdom]"

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good day,

I was installing ros based on the following steps:
https://gist.github.com/mikepurvis/9837958

The very last step, I seemed to get this error

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
rviz: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [urdfdom]
```

Can I know how I might be able to resolve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194659/installing-ros-on-mavericks---%22rviz:-cannot-locate-rosdep-definition-for-%5Burdfdom%5D%22/) by [soulslicer](https://answers.ros.org/users/20426/soulslicer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-10-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no rosdep rule for urdfdom on Mac OS. This shouldn't be a problem, you can ignore this error and go on with the installation.

To ignore the error use:

```
rosdep install -r --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

(if you're using indigo). Note the -r option that tells rosdep to ignore errors.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) with karma: 1342 on 2014-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1